# Border aligned to left under centered titles

Tags: css

I have a title tag and I want to make a small border under the title.
I use :after to do this :

```
h1:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 9px 0 0 2px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

I want the border on the left of the title, it's ok when title is align left, but when i center title I can't have the border exactly on left (responsive), if I use a margin:0 auto; the border is on the center of the title.

I have this :

[image: Actual result]

I want this :

[image: Exepted result]

Any ideas ?
Thank you !

Comment: Wrap the text in a span, use the pseudo-element on that and position it...simple!

Comment: Either make the headline inline-block (if possible), or put an additional span into it, so that you can absolutely position a pseudo child in relation to that.

Comment: Thank you for answers ! Sorry, it was really simple with wrapper and inline-block display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your h1 inline-block, you can achieve what you are after:

```css
body {
  text-align:center;  /* this needs to be on the parent of the h1 */
}

h1 {
  /* make this inline-block so it is only as long as the text */
  display: inline-block;
}

h1:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 9px 0 0 2px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>Nouveaut&eacute;s</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need the H1 to stay block, place the text of the H1 within a span like this and you can add the psuedo element to the span instead.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
h1 span {
  position: relative;
}
h1 span:after {
  background: red;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Testing</span></h1>
```